# Knockout.js preselect select multi

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a select multi that i bind to a model and i want to then select some values previously selected using a second model. I would of thought this was a simple straightforward thing to do but in knockout it seems harder than it should be. Here is what i have so far. [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbarse/TpnZh/)

A select multi

```
<select data-bind="options:availableThings,optionsText: 'Title', selectedOptions: selectedThings" size="5"  multiple="true"></select>
```

My models

```
 var initialThingsModel = [
            {"Id":1,"Title":"First"},
            {"Id":2,"Title":"Next"},
            {"Id":3,"Title":"Another"},
            {"Id":4,"Title":"Last"}
        ];
        var initialSelectedThingsModel = [   
            {"Id":2,"Title":"Next"},
            {"Id":4,"Title":"Last"}
        ];
```

Then the rest that binds the first model and the plumbing that saves and submits the selected values:

```
var viewModel = {
            availableThings: ko.observableArray(initialThingsModel),
            selectedThings: ko.observableArray(initialSelectedThingsModel),
            save: function () {                  
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/home',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: ko.toJSON(this.selectedThings),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;  charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.Message);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Problem i face is then binding the initialSelectedThingsModel so that the select list is pre populated with those items as selected.

Wide question, is knockout the right solution or would backbone provide a simpler way to achieve this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings are correct. The problem is that the objects you are passing in as the `selectedThings` do not exist in your `availableThings`. You need to pass in the same objects, like this:

```
    var initialSelectedThingsModel = [   
        initialThingsModel[0],
        initialThingsModel[3]
    ];
```

I don't have enough experience with backbone to say if it would be better, but your Knockout code seems pretty succinct to me. Not sure how much simpler you could make it.

Comment: thanks, problem now is as my models are both coming from the server, what is the smartest way to create a model of items from the first model that are also in the second model, if i did this in c# i would maybe use the following code initialThingsModel.GetAll().Where(x => initialSelectedThingsModel.Id.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

Comment: To be supported in all browsers, it's a couple of nested `for`s and an `if`. In modern browsers you could also do `initialSelectedThingsModel = initialThingsModel.filter(function (item) { return initialSelectedThingsModel.some(function (i) { return i.Id === item.Id; }); });`

Comment: what about using the ko.computed()? Would that achieve the job in some way?

Comment: Not sure how you mean. I can't think of a way to use computeds to do this.